# How to iterate through a list and match transactions

Tags: java, trading

I am working on a project to upload my trades directly to an app I am building, by consuming a CSV file produced by my broker, instead of having to manually enter trades in a journal or paying for one.

My problem is that the data is represented as transactions not trades, therefore I have to match transactions (Buys/sells) and create another object from that. The reason I want to create a "Trade" Object is to store a list of them in a database and pass those objects to other methods to calculate stuff.

Here is what the data looks like from my broker:

[image]

**Here is the Header for the CSV file:**

*Account,T/D,S/D,Currency,Type,Side,Symbol,Qty,Price,Exec Time,Comm,SEC,TAF,NSCC,Nasdaq,ECN Remove,ECN Add,Gross Proceeds,Net Proceeds,Clr Broker,Liq,Note*

**Sample data of the CSV file containing multiple examples of transactions:**

*FAKEACCOUNT,12/22/2020,12/23/2020,USD,2,B,MSFT201224P00222500,1,0.77,09:50:45,0.59,0,0,0.033,0.09,0,0,-77,-77.713,LAMP,,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/23/2020,12/24/2020,USD,2,S,MSFT201224P00222500,7,1.3,09:47:32,4.13,0.03,0.01,0.033,0.63,0,0,910,905.167,VOLANT,,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/24/2020,12/29/2020,USD,2,B,COCP,450,1.7,07:31:58,2.25,0,0,0.033,0.007065,0,0,-765,-767.290065,LAMP,e,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/24/2020,12/29/2020,USD,2,B,COCP,75,1.65,08:08:06,0.99,0,0,0.033,0.0011775,0,0,-123.75,-124.7741775,LAMP,X,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/24/2020,12/29/2020,USD,2,B,COCP,15,1.63,09:29:23,0.99,0,0,0.033,0.0002355,0,0,-24.45,-25.4732355,LAMP,,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/28/2020,12/30/2020,USD,2,S,COCP,540,1.4709,10:30:36,2.7,0.02,0.07,0.033,0.008478,0,0,794.286,791.454522,MNGD,,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/29/2020,12/30/2020,USD,2,B,PYPL210108P00235000,1,5.35,09:34:21,0.59,0,0,0.033,0.09,0,0,-535,-535.713,VOLANT,,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/29/2020,12/30/2020,USD,2,S,PYPL210108P00235000,1,5.95,09:36:47,0.59,0.02,0.01,0.033,0.09,0,0,595,594.257,VOLANT,,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/29/2020,12/30/2020,USD,2,B,NFLX201231P00535000,1,5.68,11:58:17,0.59,0,0,0.033,0.09,0,0,-568,-568.713,VOLANT,,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/29/2020,12/30/2020,USD,2,B,SPY201230P00372000,1,0.91,12:01:26,0.59,0,0,0.033,0.09,0,0,-91,-91.713,VOLANT,,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/29/2020,12/30/2020,USD,2,S,SPY201230P00372000,1,0.97,12:07:18,0.59,0.01,0.01,0.033,0.09,0,0,97,96.267,VOLANT,,
FAKEACCOUNT,12/29/2020,12/30/2020,USD,2,S,NFLX201231P00535000,1,6.02,12:21:55,0.59,0.02,0.01,0.033,0.09,0,0,602,601.257,VOLANT,,*

[image]

**Here, I matched the same transactions per color to better explain the concept. In yellow are two transactions forming 1 trade. The opening transaction is a "Buy" (B), therefore to close it, the matching transaction should be a "Sell" (S).**

**Same concept, slightly more complicated in green. The opening trade is a "Buy" with 450 as quantity. The subsequent transactions are also "Buy" with the same symbol, therefore adding to the position (450 + 75 + 15 = 540 quantity). A matching transaction to close the trade should be "Sell", but it could also be in increments. So I should keep track of quantity once a trade is initialized. See how the last green transaction is a sell of 540 quantity with the same symbol, bringing the total quantity to zero for the trade, meaning the trade is completed (Closed).**

I have made a Transaction class with all the required fields, a constructor, getters and setters, as well as a Trade class.

```
public class Transaction {

private String account;
private LocalDate transactionDate;
private LocalDate settledDate;
private String currency;
private int type;
private char side;
private String symbol;
private int quantity;
private double price;
private LocalTime executionTime;
private double commission;
private double secFee;
private double tafFee;
private double nsccFee;
private double nasdaqFee;
private double ecnRemove;
private double ecnAdd;
private double grossProceeds;
private double netProceeds;

public Transaction(String account, LocalDate transactionDate, LocalDate settledDate, String currency,
                            int type, char side, String symbol, int quantity, double price, LocalTime executionTime,
                            double commission, double secFee, double tafFee, double nsccFee, double nasdaqFee,
                            double ecnRemove, double ecnAdd, double grossProceeds, double netProceeds) {
    this.account = account;
    this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
    this.settledDate = settledDate;
    this.currency = currency;
    this.type = type;
    this.side = side;
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price;
    this.executionTime = executionTime;
    this.commission = commission;
    this.secFee = secFee;
    this.tafFee = tafFee;
    this.nsccFee = nsccFee;
    this.nasdaqFee = nasdaqFee;
    this.ecnRemove = ecnRemove;
    this.ecnAdd = ecnAdd;
    this.grossProceeds = grossProceeds;
    this.netProceeds = netProceeds;
}
// Getters, setters and toString()
}
```

Trade Class:

```
public Trade(String symbol, String side, LocalDate openDate, LocalTime openTime, LocalDate closeDate,
             LocalTime closeTime,
             double averageOpenPrice, int shares, double averageClosingPrice, double risk, String setup,
             String comments) {
    //Geting unique ID based on time
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    this.id = date.getTime();
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.side = side;
    this.openDate = openDate;
    this.openTime = openTime;
    this.closeDate = closeDate;
    this.closeTime = closeTime;
    this.averageOpenPrice = averageOpenPrice;
    this.shares = shares;
    this.averageClosingPrice = averageClosingPrice;
    this.risk = risk;
    this.setup = setup;
    this.comments = comments;
    pnl = calculatePnL(averageOpenPrice, averageClosingPrice, shares, side);
    percentGain = calculatePercentGain(averageOpenPrice, averageClosingPrice, side);
}
}
```

**My problem**: I am stuck at iterating through the list of transactions and matching them, for two reasons:

- Sometimes I scale out of positions meaning that I do not sell in 1 transactions (Multiple transactions to close trades), which means I would have to match multiple transactions.
- There is the possibility of a trade being still partially opened in the list passed. I do not know how to handle that possibility.
- Symbol could either be a "Ticker" Symbol or an Option symbol, not sure if relevant.

**What I have tried**:

From the consumed file I get a list of Transaction objects, and I though I would match transactions by symbol, side (Buy/sell) and quantity. The problem with that approach is that it might not be the same trade.

```
 public ObservableList<Trade> parseTradesFromTransactions(ObservableList<Transaction> list) {

    for(Transaction transaction : list) {
        int closedTradecount = 0;
        // Iterating through the list
        String symbol = transaction.getSymbol();
        LocalDate transactionDate = transaction.getTransactionDate();
        int quantity = transaction.getQuantity();
        char side = transaction.getSide();
        // iterate through the rest and match 
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++) {
            if(symbol.equals(list.get(i).getSymbol())){
                if(transaction.getSide() == 'B' && list.get(i).getSide() == 'S' && transaction.getQuantity() == list.get(i).getQuantity()){
                 closedTradecount++;

                }
            }
        }
    }
   return tradeList; 
}
```

I am very new to programming and handling data, and I want to do this right. Any help would be greatly appreciated because I can't wrap my head around matching transactions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your logic correctly, you would need 2 data structures in your program:

1. A dynamic array (suggest using `ArrayList`) to hold all closed trades you collected.
2. A dictionary / map (suggest using `HashMap`) to hold all open trades and access them quickly by their symbol.

Your algorithm would look like this:

Iterate over all transactions.
For each transaction, check if its symbol is in the open trades map.
--> If it is, add the transaction to the exisitng trade. Check if it reduces the amount of symbol to 0.
----> If symobol == 0, close the trade, and move it from the map to the closed trades list.
----> if symbol > 0, continue to next transaction.
--> If it is **not**, create a new trade for the symbol and add it to the map.

Once all trades are processed, the map should be empty, and you can store the list in your DB.

The code would look something like this:

```
public class TransactionProcessor {
    private ArrayList<Trade> mClosedTrades = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashMap<String, Trade> mOpenTrades = new HashMap<>();

    public void processTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        Trade curTrade; //for convinience

        if (!mOpenTrades.containsKey(transaction.getSymbol())) {
            curTrade = new Trade(transaction);
            mOpenTrades.add(transaction.getSymbol(), curTrade);
        } else {
            curTrade = mOpenTrades.get(transaction.getSymbol());

            //shortcut: this function returns true if current transaction closes the trade:
            if (curTrade.addTransaction(transaction)) {
                mClosedTrades.add(curTrade);
                mOpenTrades.remove(curTrade.getSymbol());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this code to work, you need to add two more functions to your `Trade` class.

First, add a constructor to your `Trade` class that initializes it directly from the first transaction, instead of passing each parameter individually.

```
public Trade(Transaction first) {
    symbol = first.getSymbol();
    // ... all other fields initialization ...
}
```

Second, move the logic of adding further transactions to the trade class:

```
public boolean addTransaction(Transaction newTrans) {
    //optional: add code that makes sure this transaction belongs to this trade by checking the symbol

    if (newTrans.getSide() == 'B') {
        quantity += newTrans.getQuantity();
    } else {
        quantity -= newTrans.getQuantity();
    }

    return quantity == 0; //this is same as if q == 0 return true; else return false;
}
```

This code assumes that transactions in your CSV file are in order, so that you would never need to open a new trade while you still have quantity of any particular symbol.

Also, there is no error checking.
If there are errors in the CSV file, you could end up with negative quantity of some symbol.

If you are having trouble adding such code, you should open a separate question about it.

Comment: This is very useful. One question that comes to mind after reading through the code, should I store open trades as well as closedtrades in my DB? You know, in case the program shuts down while there are open trades or if I upload an incomplete file or while I still have a position opened. In any case, I will accept your answer and award you the reputation points as soon as the function is unlocked. Thanks again

Comment: @ADSquared You asked a good design question! I assumed the program will run quickly over a relatively small CSV and have no open positions left when finished, but if your program takes significant time to process (more then a few minutes) or if `Trade` objects can remain in the open map after processing (open positions) then yes - you should definitely store the internal state to be able to resume. I would put the open positions in a separate table, assuming you are using SQL type DB.

Comment: @ADSquared Sadly, SO isn't suited for design questions, but I would like to give some general advice: any program can be designed in several different ways some of them being equal and some better or worse suiting to the purpose. There is almost never a "one correct solution" to do something.  As you are new to programming, try adding what you think is useful to your program and see how it works. Don't worry too much "is this the right thing to do". You will learn and get there! Good luck!

Comment: @Lev_M Thank you very much for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem,

1. Sometimes I scale out of positions meaning that I do not sell in 1 transactions (Multiple transactions to close trades), which means I would have to match multiple transactions.

Use groupingBy method :

Group your transactions by 'symbol' and collect as map.

Map<Symbol, List> postsPerType = transactions.stream()
.collect(groupingBy(Transactions::getSymbol));

This way you get all transactions grouped together.

2. There is the possibility of a trade being still partially opened in the list passed. I do not know how to handle that possibility.

Iterate above collected transactions and match the quantity by filtering out Buy and Sell transactions to ensure whether trade is completed.

Comment: I am exploring Maps right now, didn't know about that data structure. Right off the bat I see one problem with this, you could trade the same symbol multiple times on multiple occasions, opening and closing the trade.

Maybe a transaction opens the Map, once the quantity reaches 0, the Map should be reset?

So that other transactions aren't compiling using the same key?

Comment: No need of reset. Map works in a way like all transactions are grouped by symbol.
Eg -

Symbol1 -
 transaction1 
 transaction2

Symbol2
 transactoin1
 transaction2
 transaction3